# Replace \r\n from a specific column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to replace `\n\r` from `$4` as it messes up my lines.

Input

```
Hello   World   Example   Text\r\n    
new   line
```

Desired output

`Hello   World   Example   Text    new   line`

delimiter is `\t`

Comment: Try `dos2unix`.

Comment: if you don't care whether `\r\n` occurs in first column or fourth, you can use `perl -0777 -pe 's/\r\n/\t/' ip.txt`

Comment: You could write a simple [C or C++](https://en.cppreference.com/) program doing this. It is not clear if backslashes (or simply newlines) are in your input file. You might use [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) with [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). Examine your files using [od(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html)

Comment: If you use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) after having read its documentation, the task could be a few keystrokes....

Comment: You might be interested by [fmt(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fmt.1.html) if on Linux. Your question is unclear, and could be operating system specific

Comment: Depends what else you are doing with the file. For example, if the next stage is an awk, you can just set RS to allow optional CR. Or you can do the conversion with: `awk -v RS='\\r?\\n' 1`.

Comment: Your subject says `Replace \r\n` but your text says `replace \n\r`. Both are valid line endings for files created on different systems - please [edit] your question to tell us which one it is you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/\\r\\n//g' filename| perl -pne 's/\n/ /g`'

output

```
Hello   World   Example   Text     new   line
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
g=[]
m=re.compile(r'\\r\\n')
k=open('file','r')
for  i in k:
    g.append(re.sub(m," ",i).strip())
print " ".join(g)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.. I think you can use sed for that.
This will replace every \r\n in your file with an empty string.

```
sed s/\\r\\n//g < yourFile
```

If the output looks right, go ahead and replace it by piping your stdout to a file.

```
sed s/\\r\\n//g < yourFile > resultFile
```

greetings

Comment: Always quote your scripts (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and you can't replace `\n` in a sed script that reads 1 `\n`-separated line at a time (the default) because `\n` cannot exist in the line you're trying to find it in.

Comment: woops. I meesed up there. Thanks for the comment.